# Show value assigned to an integer instead of the integer itself

Tags: php, yii2

I have a dropdown list with string values assigned to integer values. I wanted to show the values assigned in stead of the integers.

View

```
[
    'format'=>'boolean',
    'attribute'=>'_status',
    'filter'=>[0=>'Awaiting Approval',2=>'Approved',3=>'Rejected']
],
```

This is the dropdown list

```
<?= $form->field($model, '_status')->dropDownList(['1'=>'Awaiting approval','2'=>'Approved','3'=>'Rejected']) ?>
```

Comment: In view there is code that looks like GridView data column config. Below that there is ActiveField widget. Which one is displayed wrong in your case? Also, in first one you've got `0` assigned to `Awaiting Approval` but second one has got `1` assigned to the same value. Anyway in both cases you should have proper dropdowns with array values being displayed instead of array keys. Maybe `format boolean` is causing your problem?

Comment: The status accepts only integer but I want the user to see the value instead of the integer that is to see approved or rejected insted of 1 or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GridView column config use this:

```
 [
     'attribute' => '_status',
     'filter' => [1 => 'Awaiting Approval', 2 => 'Approved', 3 => 'Rejected'],
     'value' => function ($model) {
         switch ($model->_status) {
             case 2:
                 return 'Approved';
             case 3:
                 return 'Rejected';
             case 1:
             default:
                 return 'Awaiting Approval';
         }
     }
 ],
```